# How do I merge an array of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Example:

```
var array1 = [ {'key':1, 'property1': 'x'}, {'key':2, 'property1': 'y'} ]
var array2 = [ {'key':2, 'property2': 'a'}, {'key':1, 'property2': 'b'} ]
```

I want merge(array1, array2) to give me:

```
[
    {'key':1, 'property1': 'x', 'property2' : 'b'},
    {'key':2, 'property1': 'y', 'property2' : 'a'}
]
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

EDIT: several people have answered without looking too closely at my problem, please be note that I want to match similar objects in each array and combine their properties into my final array. Keys are unique and there will only ever be at most one object with a particular key in each array.

Comment: Are you uniquely identifying the objects by `key`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a <strike>quick</strike> not-so-quick solution. The one problem you might want to consider is whether a property from an object in the second array should override the same property, if present, in the second object it's being compared to.

## Solution 1

This solution is of complexity `O(n²)`. Solution 2 is much faster; this solution is only for those who don't want to be [Sanic the Hedgehog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eo_gJwXxshQ) fast.

**JavaScript**

```
var mergeByKey = function (arr1, arr2, key) {
// key is the key that the function merges based on
    arr1.forEach(function (d, i) {
        var prop = d[key];
        // since keys are unique, compare based on this key's value
        arr2.forEach(function (f) {
            if (prop == f[key]) {    // if true, the objects share keys
                for (var x in f) {   // loop through each key in the 2nd object
                    if (!(x in d))   // if the key is not in the 1st object
                        arr1[i][x] = f[x];    // add it to the first object
                // this is the part you might want to change for matching properties
                // which object overrides the other?
                }
            }
        })
    })
    return arr1;
}
```

**Test Case**

```
var arr = [ {'key':1, 'property1': 'x'},
            {'key':2, 'property1': 'y'} ],
    arr2= [ {'key':2, 'property2': 'a'},
            {'key':1, 'property2': 'b'} ];

console.log(mergeByKey(arr, arr2, "key"));
```

**Results**

```
/* returns:
    Object
    key: 1
    property1: "x"
    property2: "b"
    __proto__: Object
and 
    Object
    key: 2
    property1: "y"
    property2: "a"
    __proto__: Object
*/
```

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/W3k4K/)

## Solution 2

As [Vivin Paliath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263004/vivin-paliath) pointed out in the comments below, my first solution was of `O(n²)` complexity (read: bad). His answer is very good and provides a solution with a complexity of `O(m + n)`, where `m` is the size of the first array and `n` of the second array. In other words, of complexity `O(2n)`.

However, his solution does not address objects within objects. To solve this, I used recursion—read: the devil, just like `O(n²)`.

**JavaScript**

```
var mergeByKey = function (arr1, arr2, key) {
    var holder = [],
        storedKeys = {},
        i = 0; j = 0; l1 = arr1.length, l2 = arr2.length;

    var merge = function (obj, ref) {
        for (var x in obj) {
            if (!(x in ref || x instanceof Object)) {
                ref[x] = obj[x];
            } else {
                merge(obj[x], ref[x]);
            }
        }
        storedKeys[obj.key] = ref;
    }
    for (; i < l1; i++) {
        merge(arr1[i], storedKeys[arr1[i].key] || {});
    }
    for (; j < l2; j++) {
        merge(arr2[j], storedKeys[arr2[j].key] || {});
    }

    delete storedKeys[undefined];

    for (var obj in storedKeys)
        holder.push(storedKeys[obj]);

    return holder;
}
```

**Test Case**

```
var arr1 = [
    {
        "key" : 1,
        "prop1" : "x",
        "test" : {
            "one": 1,
            "test2": {
                "maybe" : false,
                "test3": { "nothing" : true }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "key" : 2,
        "prop1": "y",
        "test" : { "one": 1 }
    }],
    arr2 = [
        {
            "key" : 1,
            "prop2" : "y",
            "test" : { "two" : 2 }
        },
        {
            "key" : 2,
            "prop2" : "z",
            "test" : { "two": 2 }
        }];
console.log(mergeByKey(arr1, arr2, "key"));
```

**Results**

```
/*
Object
    key: 1
    prop1: "x"
    prop2: "y"
    test: Object
        one: 1
        test2: Object
            maybe: false
            test3: Object
                nothing: true
                __proto__: Object
            __proto__: Object
        two: 2
        __proto__: Object
    __proto__: Object
Object
    key: 2
    prop1: "y"
    prop2: "z"
    test: Object
        one: 1
        two: 2
        __proto__: Object
    __proto__: Object
*/
```

This correctly merges the objects, along with all child objects. This solutions assumes that objects with matching `keys` have the same hierarchies. It also does not handle the merging of two arrays.

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/Yk5zp/1/)

Comment: @techfoobar I should probably annotate the code. Do you think it would be better to use `Object.prototype.mergeByKey`? I tend to avoid extending the prototype, but idk…

Comment: If it isn't going to be used extensively (and by consumers of an API you are releasing for example), then keeping the stock objects as they are is what I'd recommend. Just mho, btw.

Comment: @Luxelin Thanks for your answer. Looks like your solution takes O(n*m) time as you have to loop through the second array for each element in the first. Do you have any suggestions on how/if it could be done faster?

Comment: You end up needlessly iterating over elements in the second array. Your algorithm will run in `O(m x n)` (where `m` and `n` are the number of elements in the first and second array). If `m == n`, then the algorithm runs in `O(n^2)`. It is possible to do this in `O(n)` time instead of `O(n^2)` with `O(n)` additional memory.

Comment: @user3409889 My solution takes `O(n)` time with `O(n)` additional memory; `O(2n)` if we are being pedantic, but assuming numeric keys and if you don't care about having a sparse array as a result you can do this with this just `O(n)` additional memory.

Comment: @VivinPaliath There is no guarantee that the second array does not contain two objects with the same `key`—or at least the OP hasn't specified. For example, `var arr1 = [{"key":1, "x":2}]` and `var arr2 = [{"key":1,"y":5},{"key":1,z:2}]`. You need to iterate over `arr2` entirely or you miss the second object for the merge.

Comment: @Luxelin OP just edited to say that there is at most one object with a particular key in each array. Even if you had duplicate keys, you are iterating over each element in `arr2` *for each element* in `arr1`. My point is that you don't need to do that. You can traverse each array only *once*, which is `O(m + n)`, which is still `O(n)`.

Comment: @VivinPaliath Oh, I was out walking my dogs when the edit was made, so I didn't see it. A simple solution that would stop the `O(m x n)` complexity is to use a `for` loop and `break` when a match is found.

Comment: @VivinPaliath nvm, I get what you are saying. You can just store references to the objects based on the keys. Sorry, took me a bit to calm down and actually focus on what I was reading.

Comment: @Luxelin That would still be `O(n^2)` especially if keys are in reverse order: `(n + (n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + (n - (n - 1))` which gives you `(n * n) - n(n - 1)/2` which eventually simplifies to `(n^2 + n)/2` which is more or less `O(n^2)`.

Also, no worries :) It's cool.

Comment: @VivinPaliath Total tangent, but it's interesting to note that `(n^2 - n)/2` is equal to `∑(n) - n`.

Comment: @Luxelin Yup! That's basically what it comes down to because for each element in the first array you don't actually have to traverse the second array completely even if the keys are in reverse order because by the time you end up with the last entry in the first array you only have to look at the first entry in the second array.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
function merge(array1, array2) {
    var keyedResult = {};

    function _merge(element) {
        if(!keyedResult[element.key]) {
            keyedResult[element.key] = {};
        }

        var entry = keyedResult[element.key];
        for(var property in element) if(element.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if(property !== "key") {
                entry[property] = element[property];
            }                
        }

        entry["key"] = element.key;
    }

    array1.forEach(_merge);
    array2.forEach(_merge);

    var result = [];

    for(var key in keyedResult) if(keyedResult.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        result.push(keyedResult[key]);
    }

    return result.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.key - b.key;
    });
}
```

You could eliminate the sort if you don't care about the order. Another option is to use an array instead of the map I have used (`keyedResult`) if you have numeric keys and don't care about the array being sparse (i.e., if the keys are non-consecutive numbers). Here the key would also be the index of the array.

This solution also runs in `O(n)`.

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yJ9B2/)**

Answer (score 2):

It would be preferable to use existing infrastructure such as Underscore's `_.groupBy` and `_.extend` to handle cases like this, rather than re-inventing the wheel.

```
function merge(array1, array2) {

  // merge the arrays
  // [ {'key':1, 'property1': 'x'}, {'key':2, 'property1': 'y'}, {'key':2, 'property2': 'a'}, {'key':1, 'property2': 'b'} ]
  var merged_array = array1.concat(array2);

  // Use _.groupBy to create an object indexed by key of relevant array entries
  // {1: [{ }, { }], 2: [{ }, { }]}
  var keyed_objects = _.groupBy(merged_array, 'key');

  // for each entry in keyed_objects, merge objects
  return Object.keys(keyed_objects).map(function(key) {
    return _.extend.apply({}, keyed_objects[key]);
  });

}
```

The idea here is using `_.extend.apply` to pass the array of objects grouped under a particular key as arguments to `_.extend`, which will merge them all into a single object.