# Merging JSON in simpler way

Tags: javascript, json

I have three JSON strings. JSON-A, JSON-B and JSON-C. i need to merge JSON-A and JSON-B to get JSON-C and also split JSON-C to get JSON-A and JSON-B

Here are the JSONs

**JSON-A:** -> these are the questions with all possible answers

```
{
"content": {
    "section": [
        {
            "questions": [
                {
                    "qText": "Have you or your family receicved medication or treatment for any serious conditions in last 2 years?",
                    "qKey": 152,
                    "qType": [
                        {
                            "aType": "You",
                            "ans": [
                                {
                                    "aKey": "102",
                                    "aText": "Yes"
                                },
                                {
                                    "aKey": "106",
                                    "aText": "No"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "aType": "Your family",
                            "ans": [
                                {
                                    "aKey": "108",
                                    "aText": "Yes"
                                },
                                {
                                    "aKey": "109",
                                    "aText": "No"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

**JSON-B:** ----> Chosen answers

```
{
"qkey": "152",
"ans": [
    {
        "aType": "You",
        "aKey": "102"
    },
    {
        "aType": "Your family",
        "aKey": "106"
    }
]
}
```

**JSON-C**  -> Output with **selectedAnswer**

```
{
"content": {
    "section": [
        {
            "questions": [
                {
                    "qText": "Have you or your family receicved medication or treatment for any serious conditions in last 2 years?",
                    "qKey": 152,
                    "qType": [
                        {
                            "aType": "You",
                            "selectedAnswer": "102",
                            "ans": [
                                {
                                    "aKey": "102",
                                    "aText": "Yes"
                                },
                                {
                                    "aKey": "106",
                                    "aText": "No"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "aType": "Your family",
                            "selectedAnswer": "109",
                            "ans": [
                                {
                                    "aKey": "108",
                                    "aText": "Yes"
                                },
                                {
                                    "aKey": "109",
                                    "aText": "No"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

To get JSON-C, this is what I did with JSON-A and JSON-B

```
for (var i = 0;  i < JSONA.content.section.length; i++) {
for (var j = 0; j < JSONA.content.section[i].questions.length; j++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < JSONA.content.section[i].questions[j].qType.length; k++){
        for(var p = 0; p < JSONB.length; p++) {
            if (JSONB[p].qKey == JSONA.content.section[i].questions[j].qKey){
                for (var z = 0; z < JSONB[z].ans.length; z++){
                    for(var m = 0; m < JSONA.content.section[i].questions[j].qType.length; m++) {
                        if (JSONA.contents.section[i].questions[j].qType[m].type == JSONB[p].ans[z].type) {
                            JSONA.content.section[i].questions[j].qType[m].selectedAnswer = JSONB[p].ans[z].aKey;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

My question is: Is there a better way to do this? I have 6-7 nested loops which seems very difficult to understand. I would prefer not to use jquery. Thanks in advance

Comment: It should be noted that your problem has nothing to do with JSON and everything to do with JavaScript objects.

Comment: you can use [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) method to join the objects.

Comment: @Callebe: [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, so I'm not sure why `@Felix Kling` made those useless comments. You could create a recursive function.

Comment: @FelixKling Pardon me - by JSONs I meant JSON string.

Comment: @PHPglue But I would still be having 4-5 nested for loops or I am missing something?

Comment: @WhatisSober But you're not doing anything with the JSON strings. Your question is about processing the Javascript objects that were returned from parsing the strings. The fact that they came from strings is irrelevant to what you do after parsing.

Comment: Please make your question more clear. Library is closing. Good luck. Looks like you know how loops work, at least.

Comment: I wrote [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847190/how-do-i-merge-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript/24847271#24847271) answer about merging an array of objects in JavaScript. It may be of use to you.

Comment: @PHPglue Basically I want to make my code more readable. I am just wondering if there are better ways to do nested for loops.

Comment: Is the structure of the data (specifically, JSONB) negotiable, or does it need to be as described here?

Comment: In line 2 I think you want `for (var j = 0; j < JSONA.content.section[i].questions.length; j++) {`. In other words, the subscript should be `i`, not `j`.

Comment: @SMcCrohan No, JSON-B is not negotiable. This is what I am sending as payload on POST.

Comment: @PHPglue: Terminology is important when communication with other people. Yes, JSON was inspired by the syntax for JavaScript object literals. That doesn't mean you can use those terms interchangeably. JSON is a language-independent textual data-exchange format, a JS object literal is a syntactic construct of the JavaScript language and a JS object is a value of the Object data type (in JS). They are all different things. The problem at hand has something to do with processing JavaScript objects, not with parsing or generating JSON. Where the data came from is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While still four loops deep, see: http://jsfiddle.net/xh7eLoL0/

```
qkey = jsonB.qkey;

jsonA.content.section.some(
    function CheckEachSection(section) {
        var found;

        found = section.questions.some(
            function FindMatchingQuestion(quest) {
                if (quest.qKey == qkey) {
                    jsonB.ans.forEach(
                        function ApplyEachAnswer(ans) {
                            quest.qType.some(
                                function FindEachMatch(sub) {
                                    if (sub.aType === ans.aType) {
                                        sub.selectedAnswer = ans.aKey;

                                        return true;
                                    }
                                });
                        });

                    return true;
                }
            });

        return found;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things. Consider shaping JSONB, either at its source or by restructuring it after you receive it. Lookups into this shape would be much easier, and remove some of the looping:

```
{
    "152": {
       "You": "102",
       "Your family": "106"
    }   
}
```

Even parsing JSON-B into this form after receiving it would only require looping through it once...as opposed to a complete loop through it for every question.

Second, look at the `forEach` method on Array as a way to make this more legible.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

With both, and if there's guaranteed to be an answer for every question, you could end up with something similar to:

```
JSONA.content.section.forEach(function (section) {
    section.questions.forEach(function (question) {
        question.qType.forEach(function (qtype) {
            qtype.selectedAnswer = JSONB[question.qKey][qtype.aType]
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I cant restructure JSONB. I will look into forEach. Btw jsperf says for loop is faster than forEach.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
var section_A = JSONA.content.section;
for(var sA in section_A){
  var questions_A = section_A[sA].questions;
  for(var qA in questions_A){
    var qA = questions_A[qA], qType_A = qA.qType;
    for(var b in JSONB){
      var jb = JSONB[b], jb_ans = jb.ans;
      if(jb.qKey === qA.qKey){
        for(var bA in jb_ans){
          var jbA = jb_ans[bA];
          for(var aT in qType_A){
            var qB = qType_A[aT];
            if(qB.type === jbA.type){
              qB.selectedAnswer = jbA.aKey;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```