# Set the value of a variable to another variable for same keys

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two variables `array1` and `array2` as following and I want to put the values of `array2`  into `array1` for the properties present in `array1` and rest of the properties should remain the same with default values.

One solution I have is to iterate through the array length and set values for found properties and but my array is too long to perform iteration (the array supplied in this question is just a raw value).

I need some better way other than iteration.

```
var array1=[
    {
        "name": "a",
        "value": 0,
        "level": [
            {
                "name": "a1",
                "value": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "a2",
                "value": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "b",
        "value": 0,
        "level": [
            {
                "name": "b1",
                "value": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "b2",
                "value": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "c",
        "value": 0,
        "level": [
            {
                "name": "c1",
                "value": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "c2",
                "value": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]



var array2=[
    {
        "name": "a",
        "value": 1,
        "level": [
            {
                "name": "a1",
                "value": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "a2",
                "value": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "b",
        "value": 1,
        "level": [
            {
                "name": "b1",
                "value": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "b2",
                "value": 1
            }
        ]
    }    
]
```

and the required output is

```
var final_array=[
    {
        "name": "a",
        "value": 1,
        "level": [
            {
                "name": "a1",
                "value": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "a2",
                "value": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "b",
        "value": 1,
        "level": [
            {
                "name": "b1",
                "value": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "b2",
                "value": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "c",
        "value": 0,
        "level": [
            {
                "name": "c1",
                "value": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "c2",
                "value": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: @maurycy angular is not mentioned, and isn't the only library with an `extend` method

Comment: What exactly is the difference between the two arrays?

Comment: I am using angular version 2.22

Comment: the second array actually contains the run time values and array 1 is the default value to show..

Comment: @Rhumborl my bad, i was looking at question filtered by angular tag, must missclicked

Comment: @maurycy no probs apparently i dont have your psychic abilities :)

Comment: Did you take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847190/how-do-i-merge-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript#24847271 ?

Comment: suggestion with angular is also opened

Comment: I would use lodash._mergeWith(), 'cause you can define a customizer to choose how to merge things

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution with two iterators, one for arrays `iterateA` and one for objects `iterateO`. This proposal uses the `thisArg` for reference to `json2`.

Basically both callbacks iterates over the items or keys and checks if `this` is set and if the actual item is present in `this`. if not, the function returns.

The rest is straight forward, if an object is found, then it iterates over the keys and the object, if an array is found, the it it iterates over the array.

Only in the case of `k === 'value'` the value of `this[k]` is to `o[k]` assigned.

```js
var json1 = [{ "name": "a", "value": 0, "level": [{ "name": "a1", "value": 0 }, { "name": "a2", "value": 0 }] }, { "name": "b", "value": 0, "level": [{ "name": "b1", "value": 0 }, { "name": "b2", "value": 0 }] }, { "name": "c", "value": 0, "level": [{ "name": "c1", "value": 0 }, { "name": "c2", "value": 0 }] }],
    json2 = [{ "name": "a", "value": 1, "level": [{ "name": "a1", "value": 1 }, { "name": "a2", "value": 0 }] }, { "name": "b", "value": 1, "level": [{ "name": "b1", "value": 0 }, { "name": "b2", "value": 1 }] }];

function iterateO(o) {
    return function (k) {
        if (!this || !(k in this)) {
            return;
        }
        if (typeof o[k] === 'object') {
            Object.keys(o[k]).forEach(iterateO(o[k]), this[k]);
            return;
        }
        if (Array.isArray(o[k])) {
            o[k].forEach(iterateA, this[k]);
            return;
        }
        if (k === 'value') {
            o[k] = this[k];
        }
    };
}

function iterateA(a, i, aa) {
    if (!this || !(i in this)) {
        return;
    }
    if (typeof a === 'object') {
        Object.keys(a).forEach(iterateO(a), this[i]);
        return;
    }
    if (Array.isArray(a)) {
        a.forEach(iterateA, this[i]);
        return;
    }
}

json1.forEach(iterateA, json2);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(json1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```